# FineUploader: can I use addFiles() from the JQuery wrapper?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, fine-uploader

I'd like to add a second upload button that exclusively invokes the camera on an iOS device.

Per the [recent blog post](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/05/09/upload-directly-via-a-camera-on-mobile-devices/) I understand this can be done using the `addFiles()` method. However my project is currently using the JQuery version of `FineUploader.` Can I access `addFiles()` from the JQuery version or should I switch to the Vanilla JS version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access any API methods when using the jQuery plug-in.  Using `addFiles` as an example:

```
$('#myUploader').fineUploader('addFiles', filesOrInputs);
```

`filesOrInputs` can be a `File`, an `<input type="file">` or an array (or array-like structure) of either.

See the ["Using the jQuery plug-in" readme](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/docs/using-jquery-plugin.md) or the  for more details.

Comment: Ah, I tried `$('#fine-uploader').fineUploader('ios')` and got `Method ios does not exist on jQuery.fineUploader`. But it looks like that's new in 3.6. I'll do my own iOS detection and use your answer for the rest.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here.  There is no "ios" API method.  API methods are documented [here](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/docs/api-fineuploader.md) and [here](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/docs/api-fineuploaderbasic.md).  Are you instead talking about the `qq.ios` platform check, defined in the [qQuery](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/docs/qquery.md) module/docs?  If so, just reference it via `qq.ios()`.

Comment: Ah I see that iOS isn't considered an API method. I thought it was. I'm not sure of how to reference `qq` via the FileUploader JQuery plugin.

Comment: jQuery is irrelevant here.  Fine Uploader creates a `qq` namespace/global variable.  If you want to check if the current browser is running on iOS, for example, just check the value of `qq.ios();` from anywhere in your code (jQuery plug-in or not).

Comment: Cool, I didn't realize qq was a global.

Comment: For more information on utility functions available in the `qq` namespace, see the [qQuery](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/docs/qquery.md) readme.  There are also additional modules available in this namespace, such as the [feature detection module](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/docs/feature-detection.md).

Comment: Note: `qq.ios()` is only available in 3.6, which is currently in-progress (unreleased).  It's being staged in the "develop" branch in the github project.

Comment: @RayNicholus:You say that "filesOrInputs can be a `File`". In this context, what is a `File`? How could I generate a `File` object?

Comment: @IvoRenkema Please see this article on File objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: @RayNicholus Thanks. I was trying to upload both the (image)file and a client-side manufactured thumbnail. I could not find a way to do this with `File` and `'addFiles'`. I must be missing something... However, I am now trying with `canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')` which seems hopeful.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this solution:

```
<body>

<div id="restricted-fine-uploader"></div>


<div id="cameraButtonContainer" class="qq-upload-button" style="position: relative; direction: ltr;">
  <div>or click here</div>
  <input id="cameraButton" type="file" name="camera" accept="image/*;capture=camera" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;"
  onchange="$('#restricted-fine-uploader').fineUploader('addFiles', this); ">
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {

$("#restricted-fine-uploader").fineUploader({
      request: {
        endpoint: "janka/upload"
      },
      deleteFile: {
        enabled: true,
        forceConfirm: true,
        endpoint: "janka/delete"
      },
      chunking: {
        enabled: true
      },
      resume: {
          enabled: true
      },
      multiple: true,
      element: document.getElementById("restricted-fine-uploader"),
      validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ["jpeg", "jpg", "png"],
        sizeLimit: 5 * 1024 * 1024 // 5 MB
      },

      text: {
        uploadButton: "Drop image here"
      },
      showMessage: function(message) {
        $("#restricted-fine-uploader").append("<div class=\"alert alert-error\">" + message + "</div>");
      },
      failedUploadTextDisplay: {
        mode: "custom",
        maxChars: 40,
        responseProperty: "error",
        enableTooltip: true
      }
    }).on("complete", function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
      if (responseJSON.success) {
        $(this).append("<img src=\"/js/fine-uploader/processing.gif\" alt=\"" + fileName + "\">");
      }
    });


$("#breadcrumbs").xBreadcrumbs({});
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use fileUploader in basic mode, so:

HTML code:

```
<input type="file" id="btInput" name="btInput"><br/>
<button type="button" id="btStartUpload">Start</button>
```

Javascript :

> ```
> $("#btStartUpload").on("click", function(evt) {        
>
>     var filesSelected = document.getElementById('btInput').files; // FileList object
>     // var filesSelected = $('#btInput').prop('files'); // with jQuery
>     // var filesSelected = $('#btInput')[0].files; // with jQuery, any jQuery object have it's DOM element accessed using [0]
>     // var filesSelected = $('input[type=file]')[0].files;
>     console.log(filesSelected);
>
>     uploader.addFiles(filesSelected);
> });
> ```