# How to upload the files programmatically in fine uploader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I was able to use fine uploader successfully and it works like charm. But iam not able to figure out one of my requirement.

**My requirement :-**

I have information of file(file name, fie url, file size) in javascript object .I want to prepopulate the fineuploader container with the file information (basically when my page loads i want to just prepopulate(display) the files info under fine uploader container. Also i want to display delete icon so that clicking it call goes to my action class). Thats it.

I do not want any upload button just display the file info i have in javascript object under fineuploader

Comment: Apologies, but I don't understand your question. Could you be more specific with what you're trying to do? If you have any relevant code, then feel free to share.

Comment: updated my post with more details i am looking for?

Comment: I'm not even sure you're using Fine Uploader. Have you tried checking either the [Quickstart](http://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/01-getting-started.html) or the [`addFiles` and `addBlobs` API methods](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html)?

Comment: This is not a Fine Uploader question.  I suggest you figure out what library you are using before you go any further.

Comment: Sorry folks looks like my question was not very clear.see if updated post makes sense to you guys. I am using fineUploader for sure as i downloaded it from http://docs.fineuploader.com/ site :)

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675649/fineuploader-can-i-use-addfiles-from-the-jquery-wrapper

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to construct your own `File` object given the URL of a resource.  You can't do that.  Fine Uploader allows your users to upload files from their file system to your server.  You can enable the "paste to upload" feature (Chrome only) that allows users to copy an image from another site and paste it into Fine Uploader, where the image will be uploaded to your server.  If you want to allow your users to submit a resource given a URL, just send that URL to your server and download it server-side.

Comment: @ Ray looks like i was not clear in my requirement earlier. I tried to make it to the point now. See if it make sense to you now.

Comment: if you can throw light, it would be really helpful.I just want to know if it is possible i fineuploader ?

Comment: Have you looked at [this stack overflow thread/topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392069/preloading-images-into-fine-uploader-ui/)?  I suspect this is similar to what you are asking for.

Comment: Yes this what i am asking for exactly. Looks like i need to handle it myself as fineuploader does not support for now

Comment: For now, that is true.  But, if you are interested in this feature, a feature request has been opened by another user.  You can comment on the request to influence its priority.  You can see the feature request at https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/980